# Does iostream header file just contain declarations?

Tags: c++, header-files

I am learning programming in C++. I was writing a program to implement the calculator functionality:

As can be seen, I am including iostream header file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "calculator.h"
int main()
{
    //This program is meant to mimic the functionality of a calculator which 
    //support basic arithmetic operations.

    //we will ask the user to input the desired operation and operands 
    getUserInput();

    //We perform the mathematical operation and return the result
    computeResult();

    //We will print the output to the screen
    printResult();

    return 0;
}
```

Now I am writing a separate cpp file for getUserInput function.

```
#include<iostream>
int getUserInput()
{
    int a;
    std::cout << "enter your input " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> a;
    return (a);

}
```

Here also I am including iostream. Is it okay to do so?

> Because , I suspect if iostream contains definitions, this can lead to
>   a linking error related to  multiple defintions.

Comment: Yes, it is. What makes you think otherwise?

Comment: Voted to reopen. The “duplicate” is about including the same header multiple times in the same translation unit. That’s not what this question is about.

Comment: Imagine that it did contain definitions (that weren't inline, templates, etc). You'd have to do all of your input/output in a single translation unit, even across multiple libraries! There's just no possible way that would be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does iostream header file just contain declarations?

No. It also contains definitions. For example, it is specified to include `<ios>` which among other things defines class templates such as `std::basic_istream`.

> Here also I am including iostream. Is it okay to do so? 
>   Because , I suspect if iostream contains definitions, this can lead to a linking error related to multiple defintions.

`<iostream>` as well as all other standard headers will be protected by header guards or similar mechanism to ensure that the content is included only once despite multiple inclusion macros. Furthermore, they won't contain any definition that wouldn't be allowed to be in more than one translation unit according to the one-definition-rule.

So, Yes: It is okay to include standard headers multiple times. Both within a translation unit as well as from multiple separate translation units.

Comment: Template definitions and class definitions **are** subject to the one-definition-rule. That’s not the issue.

Comment: @PeteBecker they are not subject to one-definition-rule **across translation units**. Standard says: `There can be more than one definition of a class type ... class template ...  non-static function template ... ) in a program provided that each definition appears in a different translation unit ...` including a few other things. If class and template definitions *were* subject to ODR, *that* would be an issue. But, there is no issue: Headers that contain class definitions can be included from more than one TU.

Comment: For extra pedantry: I meant to say "If class and template definitions were subject to ODR *across translation units* ..." in previous comment, but I hope that is obvious from context.

Comment: @eerorika — the ODR applies to class and template definitions in different translation units. It requires that they be “the same”, otherwise undefined behavior.

Comment: @PeteBecker I edited the answer to be precise about the part of ODR that is relevant.

Answer (score 3):

You’re right that a header that contains definitions of global names can’t be included in more than one source file without causing link errors. Standard headers don’t do that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So what I understand is that including <iostream> in multiple cpp files connected via function calls won't cause an issue as <iostream> is standard header.

Comment: @JyotishRobin — right. And more strongly, any sensible header can be used this way. The headers you get with add-on libraries generally won’t cause problems.